# iPhone: Method overriding result

Tags: iphone

I have method overriding like below. Please ignore the way i written it may not be perfectly written, just for sample. But i want to know what would the output if i method overridden like this for variable "a".

-> base class

```
@interface A 
{
    int a=15;
}
 -(int) myFunction;
@end
```

-> derived class

```
@interface B : A 
{
    int a=10;
}
 -(int) myFunction;
@end
```

Lets image "myFunction" returns "a". Since, it does method overriding, when i call like,

```
B bObj; 
bObj.a = ?
```

What should be the output 10 or 15 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed you are aware you can't declare variables in a header like that and the initialisation there is just for simplicity.

Similarly, your `B bObj` hasn't been initialised and isn't a pointer

---

`bObj.a` would return 10. So would `[bObj myFunction]`. You have overridden the method and told the compiler to disregard previous implementations of this method and use the new one.

Can you suggest what the output of this might be:

```
A *obj = [[B alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%d", [obj myFunction]);
```

or this:

```
B *obj = [[A alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%d", [obj myFunction]);
```

Answer (score -1):

if child and parent both will return A then its method overriding ... but if class A's myFunction: returns A and class b's myfunction returns B or any reference type return type which has the same relation what ever there classes have means Parent and child relationship then this also know as overriding

Comment: This is a very confusing answer. I'm pretty sure it's not correct either. There is nothing (syntactically) wrong with overriding a method and providing the same implementation as the superclass

Comment: you actually.. by mistake i put there Not .. sorry .. but rest part is pretty clear and correct..